# Working with HBase EMR from another EC2 server using python on Amazon AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, hbase

I created a server EC2 on Amazon AWS and I installed the HappyBase python library for working with HBASE. 
Also I created a Job Cluster Hbase in EMR.
Then I tried to run the script on the first server on EC2:

```
import happybase
connection = happybase.Connection('….us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com')
connection.open ()
print connection.tables ()
```

But I get an error that the server is not found. As host I have Hbase cluster public dns. What I need to configure for  working with the database created in the EMR from another EC2 server using python happybase?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Did you start [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) server on your cluster master node? You can do it with

```
$ ssh -i <your-key.pem> hadoop@<master-node-dns>
$ hbase-daemon.sh start thrift
```

For this to work, HBase must be configured on your cluster. You have to choose `HBase` job type if configuring a job from visual interface.

In [old management console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/home) ensure that step `Start HBase` is present under `Steps` tab, and bootstrap action `Install HBase` is under `Bootstrap Actions`.

In [new console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/elasticmapreduce/vnext), in a `Cluster Details` window, there is `Applications` section, check that a row like

```
Applications:HBase 0.92.0
```

is present there.

When all done corectly, ssh on your master instance, and check for hbase-daemon script with

```
~$ which hbase-daemon.sh
/home/hadoop/bin/hbase-daemon.sh
```

Comment: I have tried it, but it doesn't work 
hadoop@ip-172-....:~$ hbase-daemon.sh start thrift
-bash: hbase-daemon.sh: command not found

Comment: @user2955651 First, did you choose HBase job type? You can check if step `Start HBase` is present in management console steps, and `Install HBase` present in bootstrap actions. Second, did you run command on master instance?

Comment: I've used HBase on EMR + EC2 before and can confirm @alko's answer works. One other thing to note is that if you have the EC2 and EMR in separate security groups, make sure to open up the EMR EC2 instances' port 9090 (Thrift) to the other security group.